# PHP Methods and Class Design

Tags: php, oop

Which design concept is better in PHP; passing variable to the function myFunct() or not passing the variable?

```
<?php
class A{
  public $myvar=1;
  public function myFunc($myvar){
    $this->myvar=$myvar+1;
  }
}
$myA=new A();
$myA->myFunc($myA->myvar);

// OR THIS ONE

class A{
  public $myvar=1;
  public function myFunc(){
    $this->myvar=$this->myvar+1;
  }
}
$myA=new A();
$myA->myFunc();

?>
```

Here is maybe a better example of what I am trying to understand:

```
class PhotosBasicClasses{
    protected $srcImage;    
    protected $fileImageTypeFlag;    
    public function createThumb($srcImage,$fileImageTypeFlag){    
         $this->srcImage=$srcImage;
         $this->fileImageTypeFlag=$fileImageTypeFlag;
         $resourceNewImage=$this->imageCreateFromFormat($srcImage,$fileImageTypeFlag);  //with or without the parameters is better?!
    
    }
    protected function imageCreateFromFormat($srcImage,$fileImageTypeFlag){   
        switch($fileImageTypeFlag){   //this is my problem: would be better to use the class variable or the internal variable($fileImageTypeFlag or $this->fileImageTypeFlag )
            case 'jpeg': return imagecreatefromjpeg($srcImage);break;
            case 'png': return imagecreatefrompng($srcImage);break;
            case 'gif': return imagecreatefromgif($srcImage);break;
            default: return "error  source file format";
                        }
}
```

Comment: if method myFunc just needs to increment the internal property by 1, you don't need to pass the internal property to it

Comment: This was just a simplistic concept. My concern is not how i increment a variable, my concern is about class design

Comment: There's no such "class design". Depends on what you need to achieve you are using different patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally keep at class scope variables describing your class and usually required by most of your "important"(methods tha also describe what the class can do or has) methods.

At first glance, in your case the method `imageCreateFromFormat($srcImage,$fileImageTypeFlag)` looks fine and self contained . But the method `createThumb` if all it does is what you posted then remove it along with the two class variables and rename the other method to createThumb.

If it is unfinished and after calling the method `imageCreateFromFormat` is going to crop the image and create a thumbnail, then there is no reason to have class scope variables you can remove them unless you plan to rename the class and add a bunch of methods that use these two variables.

Finally, care must be taken with class names, it is not good practice to use plural and the word class.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I guess somehow I want imageCreateFromFormat() function to be accesible from outside also, not necessarly an internal method of the class. In this case maybe I should declare the variables in the imageCreateFromFormat($path,$type). Ex: $o=new PhotosBasicClasses();$o->imageCreateFromFormat('images/','jpeg');

Comment: @Olegalex I think you should just make the functions public and remove class variables. When you call the functions you will pass the values of the variables as you just showed. Also try to revise the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of this examples is good. If you want to have object variable it's better to make it private.

By the way, your examples is doing differnt tasks, becouse first gets variable through function params increments it by one and save to object variable and second example only increments object variable by one.

Instead of "$this->myvar = $this->myvar+1;" you can use "$this->myvar++;"